# Docs not deleted although expireAt passed

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a database of documents in production that are not getting deleted although their `expireAt` suggest they should be. I can't reproduce the behavior locally - when I try the document *does* get deleted when they should.

Example of a document not getting deleted:

```
_id: "ca67081..."
accessToken: "de160..."
client: "WEB"
expireAt: 2021-09-28T07:59:10.459+00:00
keepSignedIn: false
createdAt: 2021-09-28T07:14:45.460+00:00
updatedAt: 2021-09-28T07:14:45.460+00:00
__v: 0
```

In my API I save the session as such:

```
 const sessionId = await saveSession({
      ...(keepSignedIn ? { refreshToken } : {}),
      accessToken,
      client: client || constants.CLIENTS.WEB,
      expireAt, //taken from a jwt-token
      keepSignedIn,
    });
```

And the model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { v4: uuid } = require('uuid');

const sessionSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: {
      default: uuid,
      type: String,
    },
    accessToken: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
    client: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
    expireAt: {
      required: true,
      type: Date,
    },
    keepSignedIn: {
      required: true,
      type: Boolean,
    },
    refreshToken: {
      required() {
        return this.keepSignedIn;
      },
      type: String,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);

sessionSchema.index({ expireAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Session', sessionSchema);
```

Versions:

```
db.version() = '5.0.3'
"mongoose": "6.0.7",
"connect-mongo": "4.5.0",
```

Any ideas on what could be the cause?